# Using Nightwatch: Text field takes more than a minute to read the long data but after 1 minute timeout error occurs

Tags: nightwatch.js, nightwatch

There is a text field in which a long data is sent. To read that data it takes 1:30 minute. But after 1 minute nightwatch throws timeout error and therefore, the next step doesn't execute and test fails. What should I do? I did the below as well but nothing happens.

"globals": {
"waitForConditionTimeout": 120000,
"waitForConditionPollInterval": 1000,
"abortOnAssertionFailure": true,
"asyncHookTimeout": 120000
}

Comment: Can you provide the test code? What do you mean by "read that data"? What does the test suppose to do?